# Calling variables from a return function in another function but the variable in the first return changes

Tags: python, list, function, return

I have a game which uses 21 and 27 numbers as it core values. I utilise 21 as the default argument in the function num_ofNum however in my main python file that calls these functions to play the game i override
num_ofNumbs= 21 with num_ofNumbs = 27.

The variable number_pool is just a random list of numbers ready to be indexed and dealt in the `deal_the_numbers` function.

```
def deal_the_numbers(Number_Pool, num_ofNumbs = 21): 


    math = (num_ofNumbs//3)
    print(math)
    
    
    a, b, c = (Number_Pool[::3]), Number_Pool[1::3], Number_Pool[2::3]
    a = a[0:math]
    b = b[0:math]
    c = c[0:math]
    split_number_list=(a,b,c)
    print(split_number_list)
    

 
    return split_number_list
```

here i want either the first 7 or 9 numbers in the list to become a b or c values respectively. This works as desired in this function as the math variable prints 9 when a game of 27 is chosen.

```
output: 9
```

split_number_list then also returns as desired

```
(['92', '45', '61', '88', '78', '66', '32', '12', '1'], ['99', '76', '71', '61', '90', '10', '44', '77', '13'], ['8', '4', '89', '98', '21, '65', '5', '14', '19'])
```

However when i go to call this variable in another function, rather than returning the first 9 numbers as i desire, it returns 7 numbers in the list making the game identical to as if it were the 21 number game.

```
def combine_num(split_number_list,card_column):


    s = def deal_the_numbers(Number_Pool)
    a,b,c = s
    print("")
    print("cards being dealt")
    print(s)
```

however when this function is called with its return variable being defined as "s", the same print line that was in the `deal_the_numbers` function that once printed 9 now prints 7. the variable "s" also prints seven numbers for each of the three lists rather than the 9 desired.

```
output: (['92', '45', '61', '88', '78', '66', '32'], ['99', '76', '71', '61', '90', '10', '44'], ['8', '4', '89', '98', '21, '65', '5'])
```

The main idea i have is to use default arguments that can be overwrote in my main python file so that num_ofnums = 27 and i can play the game with both 27 and 21 numbers. Any thoughts.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: Default arguments are not replaced in the function definition when you supply an argument. Each call is new, so 21 will still be default. You should have a variable which is 21 or 27, and is used in the function calls

Comment: thanks for your response, yes, so when the variable is passed it cant be replaced with the argument i want to place if i'm understanding you correctly

Answer (score 0):

Quite hard to reverse-engineer what you wanted to achieve here - next time, please try isolating the problem a bit (simplest business-scenario imaginable). I'll give it a shot, though:

```
s = def deal_the_numbers(Number_Pool)
```

**def** is used to actually **define a function**, not invoke it. If you want to call the function with num_ofNumbs = 27, simply pass that to the function:

```
s = deal_the_numbers(Number_Pool, 27)
```

If the second argument is omitted, default value (21) is going to be used.

It's pretty much explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp